# Hive: SELECT * statement works but not SELECT COUNT(*)

Tags: hadoop, hive, hortonworks-data-platform

I have HDP 1.1 on windows Server 2008 R2.
I loaded a web log in to hive table.
Create Table statement:

```
create table logtable (datenonQuery string , hours string, minutes string, seconds string, TimeTaken string, Method string, UriQuery string, ProtocolStatus string) row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe' with serdeproperties( "input.regex" = "(\\S+)\\t(\\d+):(\\d+):(\\d+)\\t(\\S+)\\t(\\S+)\\t(\\S+)\\t(\\S+)", "output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s %6$s %7$s %8$s") stored as textfile;
```

Load Statement:

```
load data local inpath 'D:\Logfiles\' into table logtable;
```

Select Statement:

```
Select * from logtable;
```

Everything so far works fine.

The following statement fails:

```
Select count(*) from logtable;
```

with exception:

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask

Edit1:

The diagnostic info in the Failed Job Table shows following info:

> '# of failed Map Tasks exceeded allowed limit. FailedCount: 1. LastFailedTask: task_201306251711_0010_m_000000'

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11185528/891391

Comment: It's not your actual error. It only says that there is too many mappers which failed. Look your concrete error in Mapper logs. There is a lot of possible cause for it. E.g. some of them here http://stackoverflow.com/a/15725084/891391

Answer (score 0):

This is rather a hadoop related thing than hive. Th reason why SELECT * works and SELECT COUNT(*) doesn't is that latter involves a MR job. What is your datasize?

Try increasing the mapper heapsize by setting the property `mapred.job.map.memory.mb` to some higher value. Also try increasing the number of mappers by lowering the split size through `mapred.min.split.size` and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: where can I find these properties?

Answer (score 0):

If the output resultset has 2 columns with same name (possible in hive/impala) then count(*) won't work.

e.g. Query #1 will give results whereas Query #2 will give an error.

Resolution - Aliasing product_code column will resolve the error from Query #2

1) Select 
a.product_code, b.product_code, b.product_name, a.purchase_date, a.purchase_qty
from 
product_fact a
inner join product_dim b
on (a.product_code = b.product_code)

2) Select * from (
Select 
a.product_code, b.product_code, b.product_name, a.purchase_date, a.purchase_qty
from 
product_fact a
inner join product_dim b
on (a.product_code = b.product_code)
) as C

Answer (score 0):

For me this particular error was an access issue. It was resolved when I connected to the DB using a username and password